# SPFX Form Customizer extension, how to prevent edits via REST etc

Tags: rest, spfx, microsoft-graph

SPFX runs in context of the user, user has to have Write permissions to the list.
If user has write permissions, the REST API will reflect that, so the user could just bypass and form customizations and write to the list with rest or graph for that matter.

So if I make a SPFX form customizer extension to override the list forms (and I somehow prevent bulk editing/editing in grid), how do I prevent a 'smart' user from using the REST api or graph from adding/editing list items?

'Turning off' rest etc from admin not an option

Answer (score 1):

This is because restricting access via client side customisation is not a suitable form of validation. I would recommend that you use column validation settings in SharePoint to ensure that the user inputs are as expected:

[How to do column validation in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-do-column-validation-in-sharepoint/)

If your requirement is beyond the capabilities of SharePoint list validation settings, then you would need to create your own mechanism for validating user entries. For example, you could create an Azure function which your SPFx customisation calls via an API which would validate the user's entry and enter the item in the list on their behalf.